# How to get array format value in json using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I added my coding's for how to create state like at the end of this question above coding's are i will try but am not able to create like that state.

This is my json format coding to get through

```
        "Results": {
            "Piechart":[{
                "labels": ["Under 18", "Age 18-54", "Age 55+"],
                "datasets": [{
                    "data": [2000, 4000, 2850],
                    "backgroundColor": ["red", "blue", "green"]
                }]
            }]
         }
```

Here is my React Code

```
this.state = {labels: [], datasets: []};

componentDidMount() {
  this.pieChart().then(result => {
     this.setState({diagramData: result.pieDiagramLabel});
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
async pieChart() {
   let pieChart = await import('../data/result_log.json');
   console.log(pieChart[0].Results.Piechart);
   return {
      pieDiagramLabel: pieChart[0].Results.Piechart.labels
   }
}
```

**How to get both label and datasets? And how to set into state like below format**

```
this.state= {
   "labels": ["Under 18", "Age 18-54", "Age 55+"], 
   "datasets": [{ 
       "data": [2000, 4000, 2850], 
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

**data.json**

```
{
  "Piechart": [
    {
      "labels": ["Under 18", "Age 18-54", "Age 55+"],
      "datasets": [
        {
          "data": [2000, 4000, 2850],
          "backgroundColor": ["red", "blue", "green"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Results from "./data.json";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      labels: Results.Piechart[0].labels,
      datasets: Results.Piechart[0].datasets
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { labels, datasets } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {labels.map((label, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{label}</p>
        ))}
        <hr />
        {datasets.map((data, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{data.backgroundColor}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Live working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-local-json-6bq4m